# syntax for accessing hash param in hash of hashes when using foreach

Tags: html, perl, hash, foreach

I've got this hash of hashes and I'm trying to populate a select box with values from each hash.  Anyway I'm having trouble getting to my inner hash variables.  I am able to generate the right number of options in my select, but I'm currently only able to set the value parameter of each select option.

Heres my hash:

```
my $export_types = { a      => {label => "Foo", ext => ".js"},
                     b      => {label => "Bar", ext => ".gz"}};
```

Heres what I've tried so far for my foreach:

```
my $select = "<select id='fancy'>";
foreach my $key (sort keys %{$export_types})
{
    $select .= "<option value='$key' ";
    if($saved_value eq $key || (!$saved_value && $key eq "a"))
    {
        $select .="selected='selected'";
    }
    $select .= ">".$export_types{$key}{label}."</option>";
}
$select .= "</select>";
```

apparently I'm accessing the label property wrong.  For that particular line I also tried:

```
$select .= ">".$export_types{$key}->{label}."</option>";
```

but that was to no avail as well.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
$export_types{$key}{label}
```

assumes that there is a hash `%export_types`. This is not the case. If you had a `use strict` in scope, you would have been alerted to this fact.

Because `$export_types` is a *hash reference*, we have to dereference it before using the subscript operator to access some value. Either

```
$export_types->{$key}{label}
```

or

```
$$export_types{$key}{label}
```

(I prefer the former).